# plugin list not appear

Tags: qgis-plugins

I use QGis 2.4 over linux ubuntu 12.04 
(a very standard situation :D)

Why does the list of installed plugins not appear in the program?

[image]

Comment: What do you get when you click on the first menu entry? Most plugins have moved from the plugin toolbar to Vector, Raster, Web or Database.

Comment: Have you tried accessing _Settings_ > _Customization_ then scroll down to _Toolbars_ > _mPluginToolbar_ and make sure they're both checked? There is also a **Select All** option.

Comment: "Most plugins have moved from the plugin toolbar to Vector, Raster, Web or Database" oh, 
OpenLayers Plugin

Comment: I found exactly OpenLayers Plugin on web menu.